# Rails Application templates remove a default gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When using a rails application template is possible to make so that some default gems (sqlite3, coffescript and sass) are not included in the Gemfile?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Yes, just modify your application template file to not include them.
take a look https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates

to get a better idea, specifically mongoid templates

Comment: it takes a blank Gemfile and than based on your wizard responses adds needed gems to it by using insert_into_file

Comment: I think this doesn't really answer the question. It just says what you should do but not how. The link, which apparently contains the important parts of your answer may also die or change unexpectedly with time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure you've solved this problem in the last 7 years, but for everyone else, the best method I've seen for doing this is to gsub it out of the file:

```rb
# Removes sqlite3, coffee-rails, and sass-rails gems

gsub_file "Gemfile", /^gem\s+["']sqlite3["'].*$/,''
gsub_file "Gemfile", /^gem\s+["']coffee-rails["'].*$/,''
gsub_file "Gemfile", /^gem\s+["']sass-rails["'].*$/,''
```